# Laravel - Convert Intervention Image Model(\Intervention\Image\Image) to UploadedFile model (\Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile)

Tags: laravel-5, intervention

The second parameter of the Storage::put method accept only \Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile(or File) model. How can i convert \Intervention\Image\Image to UploadedFile without save to storage?

```
if($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
  $image_resize->resize(300, 300);
  $image_resize->encode();
  $imagePath = Storage::put(public_path(), new File($image_resize), 'public');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to change your code to something like...

`$image_resize->encode()` to `$image_resize->stream()->__toString();` as i think the `encode()` would be redundant.

Then `Storage::put(public_path(), new File($image_resize), 'public')` to `Storage::disk('local')->put($image->getClientOriginalName(), $image->stream()->__toString(), 'public');`

**Note** that the filename is being set by the original name... i'd recommend changing that to a unique name, if you need help with that i'd start at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-generate-long-unique-name-for-filename?page=1

Comment: @FVVID no problem, happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.